# WSO2 BAM and Splunk

Tags: wso2, splunk

What are the significant different between Wso2 Business Activity monitor(BAM) and Splunk and is it possible to integrate together in the complex environment?

Answer (score 0):

BAM usually works well with a datastore. We have implemented WS02 ESB with Splunk. You can use WS02 ESB to integrate with Splunk which provides UDP support.